# How to get only base class properties from derived class?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

My code is like this

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

var obj = new DerivedClass { Field1 = "aaa", Field2 = "bbb" };
```

I have to serialize `obj` but I only need the `BaseClass` properties since `DerivedClass` properties are "additional info" which is added after deserialization.

How can I get them? (I can't use `[JSonIgnore]` decorator because I have to send `DerivedClass` objects over websocket and I'll lose informations)

Comment: `GetType().BaseType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Declared);`

Comment: Can't you just `BaseClass baseObj = (BaseClass)obj;` and then serialize `baseObj`?

Comment: Nuget -> Automapper

Comment: @itsme86 I suppose this will also plot the derived properties as `baseobj`  is actually of type `DerivedClass`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yep

Comment: @itsme86: That was my first response too, but since a downcasted item can be upcast again at a later stage; that means the derived fields are still contained within. If the serializer loops over **all of the object's properties** rather than **all the properties of the object's type**, then downcasting will not make a difference. Since JsonConvert can handle anonymous types, I'm pretty sure the former option is the correct one. I somewhat suspect that OP has already tried this.

Comment: Sounds weird to me. Why do you want to omit information of the derived class?

Comment: derived class informations are "additional infos" added after deserialization, and i don't want to serialize them. i can't use jsonignore decorator because derived class objects need to be sent over websocket, and i'll lose informations

Comment: @HimBromBeere: There are use cases for storing a derived class (in a database, as an example) using two tables: the base properties go to the base table, the derived properties go to the derived table. I would assume this applies in cases where you more often work with the base type than the derived type (which is then more or less used as a "hidden" implementation variation of your base type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could provide your `BaseClass` with a constructor that takes a `BaseClass` as parameter und takes necessary information. This way you could create a new object and serialize it:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public BaseClass(){ }
    public BaseClass(BaseClass dc)
    {
        this.Field1 = dc.Field1;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
var obj = new DerivedClass { Field1 = "aaa", Field2 = "bbb" };

BaseClass obj_base = new BaseClass(obj);
```

Comment: Better idea is to define a copy-constructor that accepts a `BaseClass` instead of a `DerivedClass` as the information from the latter is omitted anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere very great Idea. I changed my answer. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 4):

You may define a custom contract resolver which would filter out all `DerivedClass` properties:

```
public class NoDerivedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.ShouldSerialize = _ => property.DeclaringType != typeof(DerivedClass);
        return property;
    }
}

// .................

var obj = new DerivedClass { Field1 = "aaa", Field2 = "bbb" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    ContractResolver = new NoDerivedContractResolver() 
});
Console.WriteLine(json);

// Output:
//    {"Field1":"aaa"}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qailvp

Comment: nice solution! but i followed the copy constructor one... :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you map a third class that contain all the data to serialise like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClassDTO{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public BaseClassDTO(BaseClass baseClass){
        this.Field1 = baseClass.Field1;
    }
}
```

Some have propose (https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet#object-to-object-mapping). But i fear configuration will be complex for your need.

Comment: automapper would be an overkill for my case, i'll go with your solution if i can't figure out a better way :)